# Program crashes when exe.config deleted?

Tags: c#, .net

I made some changes to my program and usually i would remove exe.config before i distribute it. But now it crashes without exe.config, what do i do?

I tried removing any references to properties.settings (since there was only one) but that did not do anything, and I do not know what else to try.

Comment: Well.. if there's only one entry then it's no a hard job to open the file in notepad and delete any sensitive info out of the one value! If your code now has no use of settings you can ship the exe with an empty config file, but if you've set the project up to *have* a settings file I doubt you can just delete it; it'll have to be there with because a bunch of code you can't normally see, written by Vs, will go looking for the file to load it

Comment: How are you distributing your program, and why would you “remove exe.config”? That doesn't sound like a good idea.